# Is there any way to shorten this regex expression so that it looks more like a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have to parse a command taken from terminal as a string so that it becomes readeable by my underlying functions. The parsing function should return a tuple, containing the command, which is the first word, and the params as a list of all the other words, no whitespaces, non-readeable characters, etc.

An example of this behaviour would be:
Input: "replace all values with 15"
Variable full_command: ["replace", "all", "values", "with", "15"]

I have tried eliminating all whhitespaces in front, back and then splitting the string into a list of strings using the re.split() function

This is how the abomination looks like

```py
full_command = re.split("\W+", re.sub("\s+$", '', re.sub("^\s+", '', cmd)))
```

But this doesn't really look like a regex should look, it just seems to be a bad attempt at emulating normal string commands

The expected result in full_command should be a list of all the words from the string cmd, and it works, it just doesn't look the way i feel it should, and it really feels wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please include concrete examples of expected input and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: _"it just seems to be a bad attempt at emulating normal string commands."_ I think you _would_ be better off just using normal string commands, actually. What's wrong with `full_command = cmd.strip().split()`?

Comment: @Kevin i am required by my tutor in my homework statement to use regex for parsing the commands, not usual string commands.

Comment: It's for some bonus points at the final exam, so he wanted us to do some research, but i couldn't seem to find how to remove whitespace both in front and at the end of a string using only one regex expression, only by using 2 separate ones, and then splitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
full_command = re.split(r"^\W+|\W+|\W+$", cmd)[1:-1]
```

Edit

```
full_command = re.findall(r"\w+", cmd)
```

Comment: Make sure your `cmd` has non-word characters in start and end

Comment: I can't do that because that is only a validation measure, in case the person inputs a string wrong and adds a space by mistake or a point or something, the command will still be parsed